# Consuming web service

Tags: rest, grails, groovy, apache-httpclient-4.x, httpbuilder

I'm calling a web service like this (using [rest](http://grails.org/plugin/rest) plugin):

```
withRest(uri: "http://server.com") {
    def response = post(path: '/webservice', query: [q: 'test'])
    // process response
}
```

and getting the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RESPONSE>
    <MULTIPLE>
        <SINGLE>
            <KEY name="id">
                <VALUE>1</VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="courseid">
                <VALUE>1</VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="name">
                <VALUE>test</VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="description">
                <VALUE>Test</VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="descriptionformat">
                <VALUE>1</VALUE>
            </KEY>
            <KEY name="enrolmentkey">
                <VALUE>TEST</VALUE>
            </KEY>
        </SINGLE>
    </MULTIPLE>
</RESPONSE>
```

I'd like to convert this response to an object so that I can do something like this:

```
assert responseMap.id == 1
```

The only way I know how to do this is use Gpath expressions in the `// process request` block above to grab individual entries and build my `responseMap`. Is there any easier way? Does this response follow some 'standard' and are there functions to make my job easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do:

```
new XmlSlurper().parseText( response )
                .MULTIPLE.SINGLE.KEY
                .find { it.@name == 'id' }
                .VALUE.text() == '1'
```

To check the `VALUE` of the `KEY` tag with `name="id"` is `1`